# Android Wifi Roaming always on

Tags: wi-fi, roaming

I have a problem with an Android device with multiple access points.
The device loses the connection to the Wlan network sporadically.

If I make the following setting, the wlan connection will persist permanently.

- "Developer Options"
- under System Turn on "Allow Wifi Roaming Scans"

After a restart of the device this setting is deactivated, is there a possibility to leave Wifi-Romaing switched on permanently?

Android 6.0
not rooted